# check if pointer is null in a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I'm trying to check if a pointer is NULL in an array of pointer. Program crash when running, debbugger point to the `if()` condition but I don't know what it wrong.

In `main.c`

```
  unsigned int** memory = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int*)*MEMORY_SIZE);

    /* malloc failed */
    if (!memory)
    {

       return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Process myProcess = { 1, 2, -1};

    /* TEST THAT WORKS */
    /* memory[0] = &(myProcess.m_id); */
    /* printf("%u", *memory[0]); */


    AllocFirstFit(&myProcess, memory);
```

In another `.c` file

```
void AllocFirstFit(Process* process, unsigned int** memory)
{
    unsigned int itr_mry;
    /* Declaration of various other local variable here*/

    /* browsing the memory */
    for(itr_mry = 0; itr_mry < MEMORY_SIZE; ++itr_mry)
    {
        /* if memory unit is null */
        /* debugger point this line. This condition is never true for some reason */ 
        if(memory[itr_mry] == NULL)
        {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialise the contents of the array `memory` to NULL yourself: the compiler will not do this for you on a `malloc` call. Currently the behaviour of your program is undefined since you're reading back an uninitialised pointer value.

The best thing to do is use `calloc` which will set pointers to the null pointer value.

Comment: Ah thank you, i didn't pay attention. I used calloc and the condition is working just find

Answer (score 2):

In your code, while `malloc()`ing `memory`, you allocated some memory to the variable `memory`. You never initialized the contents of `*memory` or `memory[i]`. They may not be `NULL`, as you're expecting. They may very well contain garbage values.

So, basically, later,

```
 if(memory[itr_mry] == NULL)
```

is an attempt to use uninitialized memory which leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Solution: You need to use `calloc()` to get a zero-initialized memory so that you can at least run the NULL check on `*memory` or `memory[i]`.

Comment: Ah thank you, i didn't pay attention. I used calloc and the condition is working just find.